# Is there a way to use inheritance with ActiveMQ broker Spring bean definition via amq:broker

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm declaring a Broker via the amq:broker namespace, but I'm wondering if similar to a regular spring bean with abstract="true", is it possible to create an abstract Broker "parent" bean and have children which inherit it's properties and complete it?

```
<amq:broker id="parentBroker" brokerName="parentBroker" useJmx="true" persistent="true" advisorySupport="true" abstract="true"> 
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61636" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>

<amq:broker id="childBroker" parent="parentBroker">
    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
        <amq:kahaDB directory="/somewhere/kahadb" journalMaxFileLength="32mb" />
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>        
</amq:broker>
```

I guess not, you'd just have to use regular Spring 's then?